# How to drop indexes on analysis services (SSAS)?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, ssas

I want to improve indexing performance of SSAS 2012 server.

What I do now:

1. I monitor *Proc Indexes - Rows/Sec counter* to evaluate performance of SSAS indexing.
2. I do Full Process on the database that takes some time.
3. I tweak system setting & go back to step 1.

What do I want to achieve?

1. I want to drop indexes so I do not waste time processing the whole database.
2. Tweak system settings.
3. Process indexes only
4. Check performance.

How to drop all indexes in SSAS database? I want to undo **Process Index Mode** as explained in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174774.aspx

Comment: Do you mean to drop the indexes in the relational db that the SSAS db pulls from?   Because SSAS databases don't have indexes, they have aggregations.

Comment: I mean to drop indexes from SSAS db. I want to undo Process Index Mode. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174774.aspx

Comment: Well you can drop the aggregations manually in Visual Studio, but this is the first time I've heard of Indexes on an SSAS database.  No idea what physical form they might take or how to drop them.

Answer (score 0):

While you can run a "process indexes" on a cube, a measure group, a partition, or a dimension, there is no "unprocess indexes" operation. The only way to get rid of the indexes (actually aggregations and some internal index structures), would be to "unprocess" the object followed by a "process data", which does the basic processing excluding the processing that would be done by a "process full".

Processing indexes only, however is possible. Just call "process indexes" on the objects you want.